# How to share state between 2 combine reducers?

Tags: redux, redux-reducers

I have 2 reducers that I use and combine them. In the first reducer, I have something that gets all the initial data (which is also relevant for the second reducer).

How do I use the data in the state that I initialize/set from the first reducer to the second one?

```js
function reducer1(state = initialState, action = '') {
    switch (action.type) {
        case constants.INITIAL_DATA:

            returnstate.set('data', fromJS(document.data));

            ....
```

Then I combine both of those reducers and I want to access "data" from both of them (or pass the data as initialState to the second reducer).

Comment: Can you explain your use case?  Normally, I would say that this is a sign that you have logic in your reducers that doesn't belong there.  If you have state that depends on other state, it probably belongs in a container component instead.

Comment: one of the reducers just happen to pull the initial data - you could say its some kind of "parent" reducer - but at the end i combine them both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A reducer should return a plain object and have no side effects. If you want the same state available in 2 different `action.type` cases, then they either need to be in the same function, or a parent function needs to pass the state to different reducer functions, like so:

```js
function parentReducer(state = {}, action = '') {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CASE_ONE:
      return childReducer1(state, action)
    case CASE_TWO:
      return childReducer2(state, action)
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

But this brings up an important design point: each (top-level) reducer represents a distinct branch of the Redux state tree, and you can probably always design your data store in a way that different parts of the tree don't need to be shared. In Redux (check out the DevTools), you have a single object, and the top-level keys of this object are the names of your top-level reducer functions.

Basically, if you perceive a need to set a different state in a reducer, so other reducers can use that, it evidence of a need to rethink the store's design.

Comment: I end up injecting each of the reducer with the relevant document.data.X - but your answer is very good and ill probably use it down the road - so Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a version of combineReducer that passes the root state as third argument to the reducers.

```js
export type Reducer<State, Action, RootState> = (state: State, action: Action, rootState: RootState) => State;

export type RecordValue<M> = M extends Record<any, infer V> ? V : never;

export type ReducerRootState<R> = R extends Reducer<any, any, infer S> ? S : never;

export type ReducerMap<R extends Reducer<any, any, any>> = {[key: string]: R};

export type CombinedState<Map extends ReducerMap<Reducer<any, any, any>>> = {[K in keyof Map]: ReturnType<Map[K]>};

export type ReducerAction<R> = R extends Reducer<any, infer A, any> ? A : never;

export const combineReducers =
  <R extends Reducer<any, any, any>, Map extends ReducerMap<R>>(reducers: Map) =>
  (
    state: CombinedState<Map>,
    action: ReducerAction<RecordValue<Map>>,
    rootState?: ReducerRootState<RecordValue<Map>>
  ): CombinedState<Map> => {
    let anyDifferent = false;
    const combination = Object.keys(reducers).reduce((combination: any, key: any) => {
      const oldSubState = state?.[key];
      const newSubState: any = reducers[key](oldSubState, action, rootState || state);
      if (newSubState !== oldSubState) anyDifferent = true;
      combination[key] = newSubState;
      return combination;
    }, {});
    return anyDifferent ? combination : state;
  };
```